# Access and modify elements inside a ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2, substitution

I am testing the diffEnrich package and specifically I would like to modify the legend titles found in Figure 2 of the documentation:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diffEnrich/vignettes/diffenrich_vignette.html

eventually aiming to modify the expressions "List 1" and "List 2" to sth more relevant, like "Upregulated" and "Downregulated", respectively.
I 've tried grep to locate the expressions of interest in a couple of ways, but all attempts return the same error (mentioned below).

Assuming a function that produces a ggplot, how can someone find and modify the legend title from within the object?

```
v <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x=disp, y=hp, color=wt)) + 
                      geom_smooth(aes(x=disp, y=hp, color=wt))+ 
                      theme(plot.title=element_text(size=30, face="bold"), 
                           axis.text.x=element_text(size=15), 
                           axis.text.y=element_text(size=15),
                           axis.title.x=element_text(size=15),
                           axis.title.y=element_text(size=15)) + 
                      scale_color_continuous(name="Example plot")
```

All of the below attempts to locate the legend result in the same error

```
lapply(v,function(x) grep("Example",x))
mapply(grep,"Example",v)

#or
d <- ggplot_build(v)

lapply(d,function(x) grep("Example",x))
mapply(grep,'Example',d)
```

```
Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'
```

I appreciate your kind solutions.

Comment: What you want is to change legend title, right? There is an option called `guides()` for that purpose! Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes! But guides() replaces only the title found in the upper legend of Figure 2 from the shared link. I would also like to replace the title from the lower legend of the same Figure.

Comment: I checked that package but I am not sure if it is of `ggplot2` nature. You would have to modify grobs to make that change!

Comment: Thanks for the idea! is.ggplot() returns TRUE